# Various questions @NonNull, @NotNull and @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, nullable

I'm an Android dev who is using AndroidStudio or IntelliJ IDEA.

I tend to trust my IDE and I'm annoyed with next facts:

1. In android project when IDE autogenerates a method in java that extends Kotlin class then both IDE uses `@NotNull` instead of `@NonNull`, is there setting for this? This
2. We have `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` but when I override the method from the point 1 and I don't put any annotation IDE warns me, but why?

Am I wrong in my assumptions?
Are there solutions?

Comment: Have you checked this article about adding annotations: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html ? Also please check inspection settings in "Settings | Editor | Inspections - Java - Probable Bugs - Constant conditions and exceptions" and "Settings | Editor | Inspections - Java - Probable Bugs - @NotNull/@Nullable problems"

Comment: Checked that I see it, check that it looks like expected. But two my cases are still same

Answer (score 1):

Which annotations to use for null/not-null is set under Configure annotations... in the Compiler page of the Settings/Preferences dialog. Select the one you want and press the checkmark button. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-notnull-configuration-dialog.html for documentation.

I can't test right now whether IDEA/AS use the default annotations from there when overriding a method which already uses another, but if they don't you'll need to file a ticket.

Comment: That option is present in IDEA 2017.3.2, but is absent in AS 3.1 canary 6 :(

Comment: I see it in the IDEA but not in AS. However, looks like it is ignored when I try to generate method that implements Kotlin abstract class method